Fill nulls with following known value in pyspark
Is there any way to replace null values in pyspark dataframe with the following  value?
I need to fill null in prices in the table:
+----------+----------+-----+
|product_id|        ts|price|
+----------+----------+-----+
|         1|2024-05-01| null|
|         1|2024-05-02|  109|
|         1|2024-05-03|  120|
|         2|2024-05-01| null|
|         2|2024-05-02| null|
|         2|2024-05-03|  115|
+----------+----------+-----+

Expected result:
+----------+----------+-----+
|product_id|        ts|price|
+----------+----------+-----+
|         1|2024-05-01|  109|
|         1|2024-05-02|  109|
|         1|2024-05-03|  120|
|         2|2024-05-01|  115|
|         2|2024-05-02|  115|
|         2|2024-05-03|  115|
+----------+----------+-----+

df = [{'product_id': 1, 'ts': "2024-05-01"}, 
      {'product_id': 1, 'ts': "2024-05-02", "price": 109}, 
      {'product_id': 1, 'ts': "2024-05-03", "price": 120}, 
      {'product_id': 2, 'ts': "2024-05-01", }, 
      {'product_id': 2, 'ts': "2024-05-02"},  
      {'product_id': 2, 'ts': "2024-05-03", "price": 115}]
data = spark.createDataFrame(df)

Tried func
def fill_na_prices(data: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    return data.withColumn(
            "price", F.first("price", ignorenulls=True,).over(Window.partitionBy("product_id").orderBy("ts"))
    )

but it doesn't work.

How about this?
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

windowSpec = (
    Window.partitionBy("product_id")
    .orderBy("ts")
    .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow + 1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
data = data.withColumn(
    "price",
    F.when(
        data["price"].isNull(), F.first("price", ignorenulls=True).over(windowSpec)
    ).otherwise(data["price"]),
)
data.show()

+----------+----------+-----+
|product_id|        ts|price|
+----------+----------+-----+
|         1|2024-05-01|  109|
|         1|2024-05-02|  109|
|         1|2024-05-03|  120|
|         2|2024-05-01|  115|
|         2|2024-05-02|  115|
|         2|2024-05-03|  115|
+----------+----------+-----+

This code may still leave null values if the last row
in the partition happens to be NULL. Is that what you want?
